# Ajax function run multiple times on modal close and open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in my modal and I submit the form it submits the data and then fetches the saved data using ajax function. The problem is that, When I close the modal and re opens it and submit the form: the ajax call run twice and thrice if close the modal again reopens again submit again and so on so forth. It works fine when the modal is kept open. The ajax calls runs only once no matter how many times the form is submitted.

I have tried resetting the form in modal on close but nothing worked.

```
                    // location.reload(true);
                    $('#custgroupAssign').val('');
                    $('#varAssign').val('');
                    $('#assignStock').val('');
                    $('#assignPrice').val('');
                });


<div id="assignment_model" class="modal  fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $this->lang->line('Assign Products') ?></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="assignment_object">

                <form method="post" id="assignment_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product:</th>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <h3><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></h3>
                            <input type="hidden" id="pid" value="<?= $product['pid'] ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <?php if ($product_variations){ ?>
                            <th>Select Variation</th>
                            <td colspan="4"><select id="varAssign" class="form-control required">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($product_variations as $product_variation) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$product_variation['vb']."'>".$product_variation['name']." </option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($product_variations as $product_variation) {
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' id='qty-".$product_variation['vb']."' value='".$product_variation['qty']."'/>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="pid" value="<?= $product['pid'] ?>">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Group/var  </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Stock*</th>
                        <th>Price*</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><select id="custgroupAssign" class="form-control required">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($cust_groups as $cust_group) {
                                    echo "<option value='".$cust_group['id']."'>".$cust_group['title']." </option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                
                
                        <td><input value="" class="form-control required" id="assignStock">
                        </td>
                        <td><input value="" class="form-control" id="assignPrice"
                                   placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('Product Price') ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!--                    <button class="btn btn-blue tr_delete">Assign</button>-->
                            <input type="submit" id="assign-product" class="btn btn-blue margin-bottom"
                                   value="Assign" data-loading-text="Adding...">
                            <input type="hidden" value="products/assignproduct" id="assignment-url">
                
                        </td>
                
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="assignment-object-id" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="assignment-action-url" value="products/assign_products">

                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
                        class="btn"><?php echo $this->lang->line('Close') ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).on('click', "#assign-product", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
url: baseurl + url,
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
data: 'pid=' + pid + '&custgroupAssign=' + custgroupAssign + '&varAssign=' + varAssign + '&assignStock=' + assignStock + '&assignPrice=' + assignPrice + '&' + crsf_token + '=' + crsf_hash,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
$('#custgroupAssign').val('');
$('#varAssign').val('');
$('#assignStock').val('');
$('#assignPrice').val('');

var assignedproducts = data.products;

$('#assigned-product-list tbody').empty();

for (var key in assignedproducts) {
var currency = '<?= amountExchange('', 0, $this->aauth->get_user()->loc); ?>';
$('#assigned-product-list tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ assignedproducts[key].product_name +'</td><td>'+ assignedproducts[key].variation +'</td><td>'+ assignedproducts[key].name +'</td><td>'+ assignedproducts[key].stock +'</td><td>'+ currency + assignedproducts[key].product_price +'</td><td><a data-product-id="'+ assignedproducts[key].id +'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger rmAssgined">X</a></td></tr>');
}

},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
error_div.append('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">' + xhr.responseText + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
}
});

});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, specific the ajax, how is it triggered and so on

Comment: Resetting the form value has nothing to do with multiple ajax calls. Maybe you bind the action multiple times.

Comment: @YuduBan Thanks for replying. But Had I bind the action multiple times, it should multiple each time isn't it. The action run once on first opening of modal. Then twice when I close the modal and reopens it back again and submit the form and then number execution increase with each subsequent close/open modal and submitting the form.

Comment: @NaumanBashir I mean you bind the action each time when you open the modal but don't unbind it when close it.

Comment: ```$(document).on('hide.bs.modal','#assignment_model', function () {
                    $('#assign-product').off();
                });```

Tried unbinding it but didn't work.